# Is `Get-Help -online` in powershell supposed to work on about_* pages?

Tags: powershell

I'm new to powershell and I find myself always preferring the `-online` flag when using `Get-Help`.

But it seems `about_` pages don't work with `Get-Help -online`:

```
Get-Help about_* | ForEach-Object { Get-Help -online }
```

[image]

Is this normal? Here's my $PSVersionTable:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      7.3.2
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.3.2
OS                             Microsoft Windows 10.0.22000
Platform                       Win32NT
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the normal behaviour/known issue related `Get-Help about_* -Online`. As stated [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10306#:%7E:text=About%20topics%20don%27t%20have%20online%20URLs.%20That%20is%20by%20design%20because%20they%20are%20TXT%20files%2C%20not%20MAML%20like%20the%20cmdlet%20help.%20Changing%20that%20is%20on%20the%20roadmap%20for%20improvements%20to%20the%20Help%20system.):

> About topics don't have online URLs. That is by design because they are TXT files, not MAML like the cmdlet help. Changing that is on the roadmap for improvements to the Help system.

There are still at least two (2) opened issues related to `Get-Help about_* -Online`:

- [Online support for about_... help topics #13550](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13550)
- [Add Get-Help -Online support for the about_ topics #16452](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/16452)

There is no solution from the Powershell team yet at the time of writing this answer (February 2023) although as stated [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/2939#issuecomment-926874648:%7E:text=The%20online%20version%20metadata%20has%20been%20added%20to%20all%20About_%20articles.%20However%2C%20PowerShell%27s%20help%20system%20has%20no%20way%20to%20use%20that%20information.):

> The `online version` metadata has been added to all About_ articles. However, PowerShell's help system has no way to use that information.

You may try [Show-Help.ps1](https://gist.github.com/mklement0/880624fd665073bb439dfff5d71da886) which according to its developer supports about_*.

Comment: Browser search engines can find individual about articles.  Try search on help about_variables as an example.  This desn't help with wildca4ds.